# Syntax error: expected semicolon before leftbrace

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm new with this program so I need a little help. I'm trying to make a button in Flash 5, on which you click and it starts to play. But it alway have an error

> Sceene4,layer "button", frame756,line1 1086: Syntax error: expected semicolon before leftbrace

```
on(release){
_root.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
stop();
```

and when I write there semicolon it has even more errors.
Thanks!